# How to download files in background regardless of Application state?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins

This has been asked a [couple](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1096636/download-remote-files-on-android-while-phone-in-st.html) of [times](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1233529/downloading-file-in-android-background.html) on Unity Questions, but never answered.

All I need to do is creare an Android pluugin which downloads few files from given urls and show a downloading progress in notification panel. Downloading should continue even if my Unity application is out of focus.

[image]
<sub>(source: [cuelogic.com](http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/downloadmanager_31230_l.png))</sub>

Here is a peice of code that I have right now:

```
void DownloadFiles(string[] urls)
{
    foreach(var url in urls)
    {
        StartCoroutine(DownloadFile_CR(url));
    }
}

IEnumerator DownloadFile_CR(string url)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    while(!www.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    if(www.error == null)
    {            
        //file downloaded. do something...
    }
}
```

These are some texture files. So How do I get the texture result back from native android code?

Any king of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. At first, I used a service that worked in the background and downloaded the files I needed, including calculating progress and on complete events.

Then, I made my plugin a little more simple and easy to use. You make an instance of a Java object, providing it with the `GameObject` name and method name for the responses. I used `json` to serialize and deserialize java and C# objects, because only strings can be passed between Unity's `MonoBehaviour` objects and java objects.

Here is how the downnload looks in the android plugin:

```
            Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

            //Restrict the types of networks over which this download may proceed.
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
            //Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming connection.
            request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
            //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
            String[] split = url.split("/");
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(activity, null, split[split.length-1]);
            //Set the title of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled).
            request.setTitle("Downloading " + title);
            //Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
            request.setDescription("Downloading " + name);

            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);

            //Enqueue a new download and get the reference Id
            long downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Then you could send back to unity the reference Id so you can get the progress and check if a file is still downloading once your app is been restarted (use SharedPreferences \ PlayerPrefs to store them)

Comment: Seems good, closer to what I had in mind. But I want to know how to go for more than 1 files. For example I have 500 image files to download. And I don't want to flood the notification panel with 500 downloading progress bars (if it allows to download concurrent files). Is it possible to somehow show collective progress. In Unity I would use file count to calculate the progress (100/500 files downloaded = 20% completed). And finally, How can I access the downloaded files in Unity from storage? Apologies for nooby questions as I don't have much experience with native dev or plugins :)

Comment: you add `request.setNotificationVisibility(false)` and then just put your own notification that shows the progress.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to continue even when unity is not in focus then you cannot do it in C# in Unity with the WWW class.

If i wanted to do this i would probably write a native Android plugin that starts a download **service**.

From the official google docs:

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background, and it does not provide a user
>   interface. Another application component can start a service, and it
>   continues to run in the background even if the user switches to
>   another application.

**Services** are not that complex, you start them with Intents just as you would an activity and there are lots of examples online for this type of service.

Here is the official Android documentation regarding services: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html